# hibernate postgresql unnecessary/buggy ALTER COLUMN SET TYPE DDL command

Tags: spring, hibernate

we updated hibernate in our spring application to 6.3.1.Final, together with other upgrades (in general we updated the application from Java EE to Jakarta EE, JDK 11 to jDK21).

there is a BigDecimal type column in a table, where we didn't specify the precision/scale. in the database it is created as Numeric(19,2)

After the upgrade, hibernate generates an alter column command

```
alter table if exists DWHRawData
      alter column kb15Amount set data type numeric(2,0)
```

so, this command is completely useless, and even not correct, as i don't understand why it says numeric(2, 0)

any idea, why hibernate generates this?

Comment: DO.NOT.USE.HIBERNATE.DDL.GENERATION.FOR.PRODUCTION.